# How To Calculate Complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am a beginner in algorithms and I don't know how to calculate complexity.

```
Example:
int x=10,y;
y = x;
```

What is the complexity in example above?

Thanks

Comment: With respect to which variable? I suggest that getting a textbook is a better way to learn this than posting questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

That should be O(1) if you refer to the O-Notation.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) this corresponds to `O(1)` which basically means that the run-time of the operation is constant or at least is less than a certain constant. Ergo, the run-time does not depend on the input you have. As you may infer from what I wrote, the Big O Notation only gives an upper bound of the operation. There is also other notations which give a lower-bound and so on.

An example of a case where it does depend on the input could be:

```
int res = 0;
int[] arr = getSomeArray();
foreach (int i in arr)
    res = res + i;
```

Here the run-time depends on how big the array is, and if we give the length of the array the variable `n` then this will be `O(n)`. Again, the Big O Notation does not specify exactly how long it will take to execute but, in this case, just says that we can multiply `n` by some constant and then it will be finished within `n*some` s.

A more detailed explanation is given here: [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)